# List count of persons with different hobby combinations automatically find combination

Tags: mysql

i have a table in which a person and his hobbies are stored. i want to print list of hobby combination(automatically) and total number of persons who choose only those hobby combination. Hobby list is more than 40 so i want the list to be generated automatically.

my table looks like this

```
A-h1
A-h2
A-h3
B-h1
B-h4
C-h1
C-h3
D-h1
D-h4
E-h1
E-h3
```

that is:

```
A has hobbies h1,h2,h3
B has hobbies h1,h4
c has hobbies h1,h3
D has hobbies h1,h4
E has hobbies h1,h3
```

I was result as

```
h1,h2,h3- 1
h1,h4   - 2
h1,h3   - 2
```

Please help me find the answer

Comment: So is this stored as a different record for each person? like one row has A - h1, 2nd row has A - h2? Need more database details.. also have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I am also curious to your code, please share it.

Comment: ya everything is stored in same table and different records @ICanHasCheezburger

Comment: select per_id,hob_id from rec_per_hob group by per_id,hob_id  i tried this i got the person id multiple times @LinkinTED

Comment: i was trying lot with "group by" but nothing works for me.

Comment: this `A-h1` is two columns with A and h1 or just one column ?

Comment: please help me i am struck with it for lot of days.

Comment: A and h1 are two different columns A is the person id and h1 is hobby id @echo_Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

- `group_concat()` to generate the list of hobbies per person
- use `distinct` and `order by` with `group_concat()` to keep combinations consistently formed
- use an outer query to count each combination's frequency

Try this:

```
select hobby_list, count(*) from (
  select group_concat(distinct hobby order by hobby) hobby_list
  from hobbies
  group by userid
) x
group by 1
```

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan dude he have writed userid and you should change it to your column `person`

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan I had to guess what your column names are. maybe you should tell us what the table name is and the column names. it would make our life so much easier

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Hobbies, Count(*) From
(Select `person`, Group_concat(`hobby` Order by `hobby`) as Hobbies
From Table1 Group by `person`) Result 
Group by Hobbies;
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7437/5)**